# BLE4.0 change peripheral's name

Tags: ios

I'm developing BLE4.0 app for iOS,connecting to peripheral.Then i want to change peripheral's name,so i use writeValue:forCharacteristic:type method,a error occur,descriptions:"The specified UUID is not allowed for this operation." characteristicUUID is "0x2A00" that represent "http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.device_name.xml".And dongle can change peripheral's name.I don't know why happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm understanding your question to indicate that you are trying to WRITE to characteristic "0x2A00" which is a read only characteristic in the Generic Access Service "0x1800". If this is the case then the "not allowed operation" message appears to be correct.

Comment: Chip, this is a good question, but you've posted it as an answer. I've edited out the question part to leave just the answer for the question asked here, but I highly recommend you take the rest and create a new question for it. People won't be able to answer you here otherwise.